# Error while using methods in MapBasic

Tags: .net, mapbasic, dll

I am using a .dll file methods in mapbasic

```
declare method openmultiplefilesdlg Class "mbextensions",lib "mbextensiondlgs.dll" 
   (declaration variable) as string
```

but it shows error:

> 1. Found [method] while searching for [sub]

and for function declaration

```
declare function splitline(byval input as string, byval unit_id as integer) as integer
```

it shows error:

> Expecting sub or function

Comment: It would be helpful to post the relevant sections of code that are causing the errors.

Comment: Although, there is one thing you can check. The DLL file (mbextensiondlgs.dll) must be in the same folder as your MBX.

Comment: Make sure you MapBasic version is newer than 9.5 as that's when we started supporting the Declare Method statement.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the Declare Method statement looks like this:

```
Declare Method fname 
   Class "class_name" Lib "assembly_name"
   [ Alias function_alias ]  
   ( [ [ ByVal ] parameter As var_type ] 
   [, [ ByVal ] parameter As var_type... ] ) [ As return_type ]
```

Your statement has a few issues:
1. There's a comma after the class name
2. Your parameter statement is missing some declarations

Try changing it to something along these lines:

```
Declare Method openmultiplefilesdlg
    Class "mbextensions" Lib "mbextensiondlgs.dll" 
    (ByVal sVariableName As Char) As String
```

I have used sVariableName but you can use almost any name you want.

Also note that I have declared it as a Char type. It must match the declaration of the .NET method.